In Youtube API V3 I encoutered to insufficient scopes problem
I am using Google Cloud Console Youtube API V3 and tried to list commentThreads of my own video.
I tried different scopes like YoutubeScope and YoutubeReadOnlyScope but nothing changes. Again I faced that problem:
googleapi: Error 403: Request had insufficient authentication scopes. Details: [ { "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo", "domain": "googleapis.com", "metadata": { "method": "youtube.api.v3.V3DataCommentThreadService.List", "service": "youtube.googleapis.com" }, "reason": "ACCESS_TOKEN_SCOPE_INSUFFICIENT" } ]
    func listComments(service *youtube.Service, videoId string) error {
    call :=      service.CommentThreads.List([]string{"id"}).VideoId(videoId).TextFormat("plainText")
    response, err := call.Do()
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    fmt.Println(response)
    return nil
    }

    err = listComments(service, "p1H22env11s")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Error listing comments: %v", err)
    }


please edit your question and show us how you are authorizing your application.
